# CompletableFuture and Garbage Collection

Tags: java, asynchronous, garbage-collection, completable-future

I'd like to fire many one-off async CompletableFutures, like so:

```
for (Job job : jobs) {
 CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> job.process())
   .whenComplete(this::doSomething);
}
```

Ideally these CompletableFutures could be garbage collected after `whenComplete` has finished. But is there a risk they are collected beforehand, since I'm not storing a reference?

Comment: During the mark phase all objects that are reachable from Java threads, native handles and other root sources are marked as alive, as well as the objects that are reachable from these objects and so forth. This process identifies and marks all objects that are still used, and the rest can be considered garbage.

Comment: Note that there's a special case that when `main()` returns, they don't need to be completed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55267451/main-thread-exits-before-the-completion-of-completablefuture

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're not explicitly storing a reference, but `supplyAsync` is, internally. The method creates a `CompletableFuture` and submits a task to the `ForkJoinPool` (if you're using the common pool) that has a reference back to it. The `CompletableFuture` returned by `whenComplete` becomes a dependent on that first `CompletableFuture` and so is also referenced.

All these objects will be available for garbage collection once the `ForkJoinPool` completes execution of the `Supplier`, marks the first `CompletableFuture` as complete, triggers the second `CompletableFuture`, and executes the `BiConsumer` passed to `whenComplete`.

You're safe.

Comment: I checked the source for `supplyAsync`, and can confirm that the AsyncSupply<T> runnable submitted to the Executor holds the reference to the CompletableFuture.

Comment: Or in short, the garbage collector does not change the semantics of a program; it doesn’t matter how the completion has been implemented, as it has been implemented in a way that it will happen, hence it will happen, and the garbage collector will not change that.