# Main thread exits before the completion of CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

```
    CompletableFuture feature = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync (() ->       composeMethod ( )).
            thenAccept (s -> System.out.println ("wassup java" + s)).
            thenRun (() -> System.out.println (" imm immortal"));
    nonblockingmethod ( );
```

This is the CompletableFuture future example im working on

```
private static void nonblockingmethod() {
        System.out.println ("why  should i wait for you ");
    }

    private static String composeMethod() {
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep (3);
            File file = Paths.get ("/Users/solo/solo1.txt").toFile ( );

            if (!file.exists ( )) {
                file.createNewFile ( );
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return "   resultdaa";
    }
```

first i call compose method from supplyAsync , where i execute the method composeMethod , there is a three millisecond delay and then it will create a file and return a string as result . after its completion i call thenRun method which just prints a method , After that there is a nonblockingmethod which runs from the main thread .

the problem i face here is the main Thread finish executing the nonblockingmethod() and exits the process before the 3 millisecond delay while  the subsequent operation from composeMethod. is this teh expected behaviour or i have to block the main thread using get or join , or i miss anything

Comment: The issue is you don't do anything with the `feature` `CompletableFuture` (a.k.a Promise) once it's instantiated. What do you want to do? do you want to wait until the future chain is completed?

Comment: i want the composeMethod to be executed

Comment: This behavior can be changed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67164198/why-does-my-completablefuture-code-run-in-java-8-but-not-in-java-11

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your task provided in the `supplyAsync` will execute in the `ForkJoinPool#commonPool`. And if you take a look on the thread in the `common pool` you can see that they are **`Deamon thread`**, that means JVM will not wait to Shutdown for that daemon thread to complete its execution when there is no `active non-daemon thread`.In your case, you have a sleep in `composeMethod` and in the meantime, main thread executes and completed its work, and `JVM does not have any active non-daemon thread`.So,  JVM will go to `shut down` without waiting for your task to complete. If you run the below example you can confirm about the thread pool and type of thread.

```
CompletableFuture feature = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    System.out.println("Thread : " + Thread.currentThread());
    System.out.println("Is Daemon : " + Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
    return composeMethod();
}).thenAccept(s -> System.out.println("wassup java" + s)).thenRun(() -> System.out.println(" imm immortal"));
```

Output:

```
Thread : Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1,5,main] // This line may be bit different but it indicates that your task is executing on Common pool
Is Daemon : true
why  should i wait for you
```

> To resolve the issue you can pass your own executor like below:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
CompletableFuture feature = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("Thread : " + Thread.currentThread());
        System.out.println("Is Daemon : " + Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
        return composeMethod();
    }, executorService).thenAccept(s -> System.out.println("wassup java" + s))
            .thenRun(() -> System.out.println(" imm immortal"));
executorService.shutdown();
nonblockingmethod();
```

Output:

```
Thread : Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]
Is Daemon : false
why  should i wait for you 
wassup java   resultdaa
 imm immortal
```

Comment: Thanks , but if i provide my own executor service , then also i  face the same problem

Comment: @javaworld You should not face the same problem. Did you have tried bypassing the own executor? I have added the example in my answer and it is working fine for me.

Comment: I don't think program will run to complete with this solution (providing its own executor).

Comment: yes it worked , i messed up with running thenAcceptAsync and thenrunAsync supplying the Executor service once i applied your solution it worked fine

Comment: @LaksithaRanasingha Why do you think like that? Can you please explain a bit.

Comment: The application never runs to completion, it hangs after printing imm immortal. Tried on Java 11.

Comment: @LaksithaRanasingha Yes, it actually does not hangs. JVM still has some active thread running as  I forgot to add shut down the Executor. I have added a shutdown call of the executor to my answer. Thanks!!!

Comment: @AmitBera great that's the missing piece of the puzzle.