# Why does my CompletableFuture code run in Java 8 but not in Java 11?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, java-11, completable-future

Why does this block of code behave differently in Java 8 vs Java 11?

```
private static String test2() {
    CompletableFuture
            .runAsync(() -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).forEach(x -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    System.out.println(x);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }));

    return "Finish";
}
```

I expected it to print Finish and then for numbers from 1 to 20 with a 500 ms interval print that number, and then stop execution, and it works correctly in Java 8.

When I run exactly the same method on Java 11, however, it printed Finish and terminated without invoking the runAsync(...) code. I managed to start it by adding an ExecutorService like this

```
private static String test2() {

    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    CompletableFuture
            .runAsync(() -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).forEach(x -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    System.out.println(x);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }), executorService);

    return "Finish";
}
```

And now it gets executed, but doesn't finish; it gets to 10 and after that just sits without finishing. I figured out how to stop execution by invoking `executorService.shutdown();` right before return, but I am 100% sure that this approach is wrong, because usually I will have the same executorService for many methods, and if I shut it down other methods will also fail to execute.

What changed between Java 8 and Java 11 here, and why do I now have to add an explicit executor service, and most importantly how can I finish the method execution properly?

Comment: "but I am 100% sure that this approach is wrong" why though? create a pool for this method _only_ with a single (or any other little sensible number of threads) and never shut it down. How do you think tomcat for example works internally? it creates some pools, never shuts them down. There is nothing wrong in doing this. Weirdly enough, we are from the same city :|

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** - add `ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`  after your call to `CompletableFuture.runAsync` **and at the end of your code** so that `System.exit` doesn't stop your runnable. That way you'll get you behavior.

---

**Longer answer:**

Okay, so first things first, I tried both examples in Oracles java 8, OpenJDK 8, and OpenJDK 11. Consistent behavior across the board, so my answer is that *nothing* has changed in these implementations of different java versions that would cause this discrepancy. In **both** examples, the behavior you see is consistent with what Java tells you it will do.

From the documentation of `CompletableFuture.runAsync`

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a task running in the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` after it runs the given action.

Okay... let's see what `ForkJoinPool.commonPool` will tell us (emphasis mine):

> Returns the common pool instance. This pool is statically constructed; its run state is unaffected by attempts to `shutdown()` or `shutdownNow()`. **However this pool and any ongoing processing are automatically terminated upon program `System.exit(int)`**. Any program that **relies on asynchronous task processing to complete before program termination should invoke `commonPool().awaitQuiescence`**, before exit.

Aha, so that's why we don't see the countdown when using the common pool, it's because the common pool will be terminated upon system exit, which is exactly what happens when we return from the method and exit the program (assuming your example is really that simple as you show it.... like with a single method call in `main`... anyways)

So why would the custom executor work? Because, as you've already noticed, that executor has not been terminated. There is still a piece of code running in the background, although idly, that Java doesn't have the power to stop.

---

So what can we do now?

**One** option is to do our own executor and shut it down once we are done, much like you have suggested. I would argue that this approach **isn't** all that bad after all to use.

**Second** option is to follow what the java doc says.

> Any program that relies on asynchronous task processing to complete before program termination should invoke `commonPool().awaitQuiescence`, before exit.

> public boolean awaitQuiescence​(long timeout,
> TimeUnit unit)
>
> If called by a ForkJoinTask operating in this pool, equivalent in effect to ForkJoinTask.helpQuiesce(). Otherwise, waits and/or attempts to assist performing tasks until this pool isQuiescent() or the indicated timeout elapses.

So we can call that method and specify a timeout for all common processes in the common pool. My opinion is that this is somewhat *business specific*, since now you have to answer the question - **What the heck should the timeout be now??**.

**Third** option is to use the power of `CompletableFuture`s and hoist this `runAsync` method to a variable:

```java
CompletableFuture<Void> voidCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> ...
...
...
bla bla bla code bla bla bla
...
...
voidCompletableFuture.join();
// or if you want to handle exceptions, use get
voidCompletableFuture.get();
```

and then right when you need it, you `join()/get()` whatever you need to have as a return value. I prefer this the most since the code is most clean and understandable like this. Also I can *chain* my CFs all I want and do funky stuff with them.

---

**In the case** where you don't need a return value and don't need to do anything else and just want a simple return of a string and async processing of counting from 1 to 20, then just shove `ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` somewhere convenient to you and give it some ridiculous timeout, thus **guaranteeing** you'll exit upon all *idle* processes.

Comment: Why should it change anything in the process to replace `get()` with `join()`? Both have the exact same source, with the only difference that `join()` does not throw any `Exception`s.

Comment: I guess I used join rather by instinct since I use it more than get. I'll update my answer to accommodate for get as well.

Comment: @Kaplan `join()` does not throw *checked* exceptions. It still does throw exceptions, i.e. `CancellationException` or `CompletionException`, but you don’t need to catch them.

Comment: @Holger Thank you. The wording was sloppy. In fact, it's all about the checked exceptions `ExecutionException` and `InterruptedException` that `get()` have and `join()` have not.

Answer (score 1):

*if it has to be* `CompletableFuture`

```
private static String test2() {
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync( () -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).forEach(x -> {
          try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
          }
          catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          System.err.println(x);
        })).get();
      }
      catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }});
    return "Finish";
}
```

---

*I think you would be better off with this alternative to* `CompletableFuture`

```
private static String test2() {
    Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).forEach(x -> {
            try {
              Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(x);
          });
      }
  };
  Executors.newCachedThreadPool().execute(runner);
  return "Finish";
}
```

Comment: It will work, but not like I need and expect it will execute, runAsync(..) code and after this will return finish , but I need inverse.

Comment: `CompletableFuture` is just there to give You control for the outcome of a `Future`. But you want to achieve something simpler. *(see above)*

Answer (score 1):

I would say your program just behaves as expected. `runAsync` will run the provided action in the common fork join pool, unless you provide an executor.
In any case, if you don't wait for your completable future to complete, the method `test2` immediately prints "Finish" and returns.

"Finish" could just been printed an any time: you may see "Finish, 1, ..." or  "1, Finish, 2..." etc... It's a race condition.

When you don't use an executor, because threads in the common pool are daemon threads, your program may exit at any time, and won't wait for the scheduled action to complete.

When you use an executor with non daemon threads (which is usually the default), the program won't exit until the executor is shutdown.

The only way to make sure that your program doesn't exit before your action is finished is to wait for the completable future to complete, calling either [get](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get()) or [join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join()) as was suggested in the other answer.

Comment: But I need to immediately return "Finish" and after this execute that runAsync(...) code and finish method execution, how can I obtain such a behaviour.

Comment: You should return the CompletableFuture instead. Then your caller could wait for it to finish, or register a dependent action, or do anything that needs done when the action completes. `return CompletableFuture.runAsync(...);`

Comment: Hm ok will take that in count , but what if I have a really heavie operation, for example I have to upload 300 images to S3 , I'd like to do it asyncronous , in background but user will receive a message saying "Process was started" how should I handle this ? Any ideea ?

Comment: Printing an message _"Process was started"_ instantly is trivial. Do it in the first line of `runAsync()`. This will of course not help with Your first problem to immediately return  from the function `test2()` to get the `"Finish"` result value.